# How do I calculate at $z=0$ the power series of the analytic function $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{1-z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I calculate at $z=0$ the power series of the analytic function $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{1-z}$?

What I have done:

Multiply the power series for $(1-z)^{-1}=1+z+z^2…$ times the series for $e^z=1+z+z^2/2 …$
and the coefficient of each $z^n$ will be $\Sigma_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{i!}$

Is this good?

Or I should use Cauchy product?

Comment: What would be different if you used the Cauchy product?

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy product is just the formula for the coefficients of the product of two infinite series, which is what you've already found (by some other means):

$$
\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jz^j\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jz^j \right) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j z^j,\quad c_j = \sum_{\ell = 0}^ja_\ell b_{j-\ell}
$$  So in your case, $a_j = 1/j!$ and $b_j = 1$ for all $j$.  Thus

$$
\frac{\exp(z)}{1-z}=\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j!}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j \right) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_jz^j,\quad c_j = \sum_{\ell=0}^j \frac{1}{j!}\cdot 1
$$  Of course, this series is only valid for $\vert z\vert<1$, but I'm sure you already knew that.